# Randomizing texture coordinates has no effect on displacement texture position

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement, instances, texture-coordinates

I have run into the same problem as this old unanswered question, [Cycles displacement material wrong uv mapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79024/cycles-displacement-material-wrong-uv-mapping)

I can shift the vector coordinates of PBR textures on instances of dupliverts to break up texture repetition across instanced objects.  But the displacement node seems to apply the same coordinates to all instanced objects and is out of sync with the PBR texture.

Can I change the material to sync up displacement and PBR textures.

[image]

Here is a sample blend -- [image]

Comment: AFAIK this is a limitation of true displacement and instancing objects. You can work around it by using an array modifier across a curve for instance, or plain old ALT D linked duplicate

Comment: I suspected that might be the case but I wanted to make sure I had not missed anything. I guess that means there are different kinds of "instances?"

Comment: In the case of the array modifier, the geometry is actually duplicated so you don't really gain much from instancing optimizations, and when using ALT + D, the objects are different, but their data (= geometry) points to the same place. In short yes, there are multiple ways to "instance" geometry. The least heavy computationally, object or collection instance, is also heavily optimized which means that apparently, for now at least, the actual displaced geometry can't be different in the instances, while other properties such as color can indeed be different